# MonoDevelop doesn't Run

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I have the latest version 2.10 though mono run button is off whenever I'm ready to test a program.Pervious version had run/run with menu ready when I was done but now it's turned off.

Comment: 2.10 isn't a real MonoDevelop version. Please provide details of the kind of project, the MD version, the Mono version,and your OS.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to reinstall it? If you haven't done that, but do it.

Regards